# Getting error Usually a PL/SQL compilation error. when i parse bind variable in where condition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When i try to parse bind variable in where condition i am getting the following error. when i remove the where condition the query works fine.

Error :

```
ORA-06550: line 17, column 26:
PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
ORA-06550: line 17, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

Quer :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
v_sql varchar2(500);
v_sql2 varchar2(500);
 v_prj_id varchar2(4000):='B00781728,B00781628,B00781611,A43670001';
v_event  varchar2(500) := 'CORE_DTS_INTERNAL';

BEGIN

FOR i IN (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(v_prj_id, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
         FROM dual 
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(v_prj_id, ',') + 1 
) LOOP


   v_sql :=  v_sql || 'select '''|| i.l ||''' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ' || i.l || '.SI_Recipient WHERE EVENT = :1 UNION ALL ' || chr(10)   ;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  STRING USING v_event;

END LOOP;

v_sql2 :=  RTRIM(v_sql, 'UNION ALL ' || chr(10) ) || ';';

Dbms_Output.Put_Line (v_sql2);

END;
```

Comment: You probably don't want to do this. See [my comment on @Tejash answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58930732/146325). Basically you need to concatenate the value of `v_event` in the generated string.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, there is an issue with following statement:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  STRING USING v_event;
```

What is `STRING` here?

second, Why `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is there in the loop. and there are several other issues so Your code should look something like this.

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2      V_SQL      VARCHAR2(500);
  3      V_SQL2     VARCHAR2(500);
  4      V_PRJ_ID   VARCHAR2(4000) := 'B00781728,B00781628,B00781611,A43670001';
  5      V_EVENT    VARCHAR2(500) := '1'; -- change it accordingly
  6  BEGIN
  7      FOR I IN (
  8          SELECT
  9              TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(V_PRJ_ID, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) L
 10          FROM
 11              DUAL
 12          CONNECT BY
 13              LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(V_PRJ_ID, ',') + 1
 14      ) LOOP
 15          V_SQL := V_SQL
 16                   || 'select '''
 17                   || I.L
 18                   || ''' AS "PRJ_ID" from DUAL'
 19                   || ' WHERE 1 = :1 UNION ALL '
 20                   || CHR(10);
 21
 22  -- commented by tejash
 23
 24  --        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE RTRIM(V_SQL, 'UNION ALL ' || CHR(10))
 25  --            USING V_EVENT;
 26      END LOOP;
 27
 28      V_SQL2 := RTRIM(V_SQL, 'UNION ALL ' || CHR(10));
 29  --              || ';';  -- commented by tejash
 30      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_SQL2);
 31      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL2
 32          USING V_EVENT, V_EVENT, V_EVENT, V_EVENT; -- 4 times used as there are four bind variables
 33  END;
 34  /
select 'B00781728' AS "PRJ_ID" from DUAL WHERE 1 = :1 UNION ALL
select
'B00781628' AS "PRJ_ID" from DUAL WHERE 1 = :1 UNION ALL
select 'B00781611' AS
"PRJ_ID" from DUAL WHERE 1 = :1 UNION ALL
select 'A43670001' AS "PRJ_ID" from
DUAL WHERE 1 = :1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: `-- 4 times used as there are four bind variables` highlights a limitation of using NDS like this: if there are five schemas in the V_PRJ_ID string the loop will generate five SELECT statements which means there needs to be five assignments of the bind variable value. Which we can't do as the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE call is hard-coded.

Comment: Yes, you are right @APC . It should not be done like this.